# How can I view list of values in a one column by MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I set a list of values by MYSQL in one column like the following query:

```
SELECT (100005355, 100001548, 100000672, 100001230, 100003382, 100009937, 100003778, 100002486, 100003301, 100005056, 100003435, 100003666, 100002761, 100008818, 100008341, 100003438, 100000581, 100009800, 100007165) AS ID;
```

result needs to be like this list

[image: result needs to be like this list]

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of what you *really* want to do and what the problem is you are trying to solve. Depending on what you want to do you can rewrite your SQL query in a query where you use an `WHERE id IN (...)` expression.

Comment: Note that SQL is for the storage and retrieval of relational data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 100005355 AS ID UNION ALL
SELECT 100001548 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100000672 UNION ALL 
SELECT .....
```

If you want to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename AS
SELECT 100005355 AS ID UNION ALL
SELECT 100001548 UNION ALL 
SELECT 100000672 UNION ALL 
SELECT .....
```

In MySql 8.0+ you can use the `VALUES` statement with `ROW` constructor:

```
WITH cte(ID) AS (VALUES ROW(100005355), ROW(100001548), ROW(100000672))
SELECT * FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86948993f0db90859cd012f40f2fc908).

Answer (score 0):

if you want just show the value you could try using group_concat

```
select group_concat(id) as my_col
from your_table
```

or use the saperator you prefer

```
select group_concat(id separator ', ')  as my_col
from your_table
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried this
select CONCAT_WS("
", 100005355, 100001548, 100000672, 100001230, 100003382, 100009937, 100003778, 100002486, 100003301, 100005056, 100003435, 100003666, 100002761, 100008818, 100008341, 100003438, 100000581, 100009800, 100007165 ) AS ID;